# Convert a mutable Map of Seq to an immutable Map of IndexedSeq in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, immutability

I need to process a large number of records (several million) representing people. I would like to create a partition based on the year-of-birth, and then process each group separately. I am trying to create a functional solution (no/minimal mutable data), so that it will be thread-safe and can be parallelized.

For my first attempt, I created a tail-recursive function that builds a `Map[Int, IndexedSeq]` that maps each year-of-birth to a sequence of people records. I need an indexed sequence because I will be doing random accesses to the people in each group. Here is my code:

```
@tailrec
def loop(people: Seq[Person],
         map: Map[Int, IndexedSeq[Person]] = Map()): Map[Int, IndexedSeq[Person]] = {
  if (people.isEmpty) map
  else {
    val person = people.head
    val yearOfBirth = person.yearOfBirth
    val seq = map.getOrElse(yearOfBirth, IndexedSeq())
    loop(people.tail, map + (yearOfBirth -> (seq :+ person)))
  }
}
```

This works, but is not very efficient. I can do better by allowing a small amount of very localized mutability. If all of the mutable variables are on the stack, the code will still be thread-safe, as long as the output `Map` is immutable.

I would like to implement this by internally building a mutable `Map[Int, List[Person]]` and then efficiently converting it to an immutable `Map[Int, IndexedSeq[Person]]` as the return value.

How can I convert the mutable `Map` of `List` items to an immutable `Map[Int, IndexedSeq[Person]]` in the most efficient manner possible? Note that there is no particular order to the people in each year-of-birth group.

Comment: A minor point, probably irrelevant: since you're partitioning on year-of-birth, AFAICT you'll never pass the map itself outside of this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the `groupBy`function of the `Seq` trait? (documentation is here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq)

```
def groupByYearOfBirth(people: Seq[Person]) = people.groupBy(_.yearofBirth)
```

**Edit:** contrary to my initial proposition, don't use `.mapValues(_.toIndexedSeq)` `to provide an`IndexedSeq`. Daniel explains why in a comment below.

Comment: I did not use your technique because I did not know about it. :-) It looks like it will do **exactly** what I need. Isn't Scala great?! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's always the same in scala: look carefully at the API first, most of the time, it contains exactly what you need. ;)

Comment: Do *NOT* use `mapValues` that way! The implementation of `mapValues` works like a view, which means it will apply that conversion every time you access that value. Given the difference between `Seq` and `IndexedSeq`, it is quite likely doing it this way won't gain you anything. Use a normal `map` instead, to create a new `Map`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, I didn't know that it evaluates the new value at each access.